# Insufficient Privileges for mass update

Tags: field-level-security

I have 6 different User Profiles. One of the Users type wants to be able to do a mass update on their opportunities. so they click on opportunities tab , then select the right view. and click on go beside it.  Select few opportunities and then they click on Mass update . "Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Click here to return to the previous page. "

I am playing with the role persmission , but so far I dont know how they can get an access to this mass update.

Comment: What's your default org wide access setting for opportunities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass Update for Opportunities is not an out-of-the-box functionality. It is probably a AppExchange add on like https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018mbBEAQ

Make sure that user profile have:

1. Edit permission on Opportunities
2. Your OWD sharing rules are set to public read/write or a sharing rule exists to share the opportunities with these users
3. Access to the pages/class/components of the package allowing the Mass Update function.

Answer (score 1):

I use the native app Smart-Mass-Update to mass-update / mass-create / mass-edit / mass-clone they even have field-search, view-search and more other cool features.

Smart Mass Update on the AppExchnage: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4KmAEAV

Smart Mass Update website: http://www.zaapit.com/page/smart-mass-update

[image]